# Check APEX exception type

Tags: exception, apex-code

I'm looking to check what type of exception is retruned in the following code snippet.
I'm not sure exactly how to do it though, or if it's even possible.

```
try {
    //SOME LOGIC
} catch (exception ex) {
    System.debug(//EXCEPTION TYPE);
}
```

Would anyone have any suggestions or advice??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching around I found an answer,

```
try {
    //SOME LOGIC
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.debug(ex.getTypeName()); 
}
```

The [getTypeName()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) method does the trick nicely.

I apologise for not specifying I was working in Apex in my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
//SOME LOGIC
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getClass().getName());
}
```

Few things:

1. You have posted exception. I assume you meant Exception.
2. System.debug does not exist.
3. I have answered your specific question but obviously this is not standard exception handling code. You will instead output the stacktrace, log the exception or rethrow a different one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer JamesB, but I'm getting the following error,

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Exception].getClass()

Comment: Something else must be wrong with your code. The getClass method belongs to java.lang.Object so every object has this method.

Comment: Same for me, does not look like apex exception class has this method. ex.getTypeName() works neat.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, within your `catch` block(s), specify the exception. Semantically, `type`s including `Exception` are not in camel case.

Secondly, you can obtain the exception type through `Exception.getClass().getName()`:

```
catch (Exception exception) {
    System.out.println(exception.getClass().getName());
    // exception.printStackTrace();
    // throw exception;
}
```

> Specified by:
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html